# How to verify it's the same computer

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's any Python code I can run that, assuming the Python code has not been tampered with, will return an ID specific to that computer that cannot be spoofed. My initial thought was to use MAC addresses, but I know those can be easily spoofed. How about CPU serial number? How would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: Owner replaces the CPU, now the CPU serial number has changed. Does that constitute "not running on the same computer" for you? What is it that you *really* want to verify?

Comment: @chepner I'm trying to build software licensing that only allows it to be run on one computer at once.

Comment: So you want to prevent the licensee from uninstalling the software from one computer and using it on another of their choice?

Comment: @chepner No I will allow them to change, it's just important that it's only on one computer at a time and therefore I need a way of checking if the computer they are using the software on is the same one they have registed it for.

Comment: Implementing a software license enforcement system also known under the euphemism "DRM system" usually asks more questions than it answers. In any case solving even one of the main problem is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an impossible problem, as it's equivalent to effective DRM. Every identifier can be spoofed. Remember, the user **can** tamper with your Python code (any compiling/obfuscating/encrypting you do can be reversed, so don't bother) to return whatever identifier they want. (And even if your code were absolutely read-only, they could change the Python runtime or the OS to do whatever they want.)

Comment: How come software licensing companies use it? https://netlicensing.io/licensing-models/

Comment: They use it to keep honest people honest, since it's effective against people who don't bother to spoof it. People who want to pirate the software still can.

Comment: OK well how would I get the CPU serial number in Python?

Comment: Before worrying about that, worry about how you are going to prevent the licensee from tampering with the software to avoid the CPU check in the first place. You can assume anything you like, but that's not going to make your license enforcement any more useful.

Comment: @chepner It's not a problem to re-write the program in C++ which is more difficult to tamper with. I just want to know how to get a unique computer ID that's difficult to spoof.

Comment: Going from Python to C++ doesn't make it "difficult" to spoof. It moves it from "very easy" to "moderate" at best.

Comment: I said "more difficult" when speaking about the languages. I don't want it to be easy. I would say being in C++ plus algorithmic and manual obfuscation methods will make it difficult. Anyway, what I need is a way to fingerprint a device that isn't easy to spoof.